# Programmatically determine if a variable's value was computed at compile time or at run time

Tags: c, constants

Is there a way in C to programmatically determine that variable's value was computed at compile time or at run time?

Example:

```
const double a = 2.0;
const double b = 3.0;
double c1 = a / b; // done at compile time (constant folding / propagation)
double c2 = *(volatile double*)&a / *(volatile double*)&b; // done at run time
compute_time_t c1_ct = compute_time(c1);
compute_time_t c2_ct = compute_time(c2);
assert(c1_ct == COMPILE_TIME);
assert(c2_ct == RUN_TIME);
```

Comment: This should probably be two different questions for C and C++ respectively.

Comment: For C, I don't think there's anything in the standard language, but GCC for instance has `__builtin_constant_p()`.

Comment: There are no requirements in the standard C or C++  for the compiler to flag whether an expression is evaluated at compile time (constant) or run-time.  There is no attribute that the program can access.  This due largely to the "as-if" rule:  the compiler can make substitutions as long as the behavior doesn't change (as if the optimization didn't occur).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: `constexpr int compileTime = c1; std:: integral_constant<compileTime> t{};` will enforce it in C++

Comment: FYI, floating point values cannot be compared for exact equality, due to the nature of representing values in floating point format.

Comment: If `compute_time_t` is a floating point type, you might be able to abuse `_Static_assert(c1_ct == c1_ct)`.  If it can be found at compile time, the assertion will pass, but if not, the assertion will fail on the grounds that it might be NaN.

Comment: I'm going to "boldly" edit this into a question about C only.  Please feel free to post a separate one for C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Floating-point values can be compared for exact equality, due to their specifications. Not that it has anything to do with this question, as the code shown does not compare `c1` and `c2`, directly or indirectly.

Comment: And under some circumstances it even makes sense to compare floating-point values for exact equality.

Comment: Re “Is there a way in C to programmatically determine that variable's value was computed at compile time or at run time?”: Well, you could isolate the relevant source code, use the result as a static initializer, then invoke the compiler on this source code, and see whether it reports an error. Whether it does or not would be a good indication that the compiler is not or is (respectively) able to evaluate the expression at compile-time, and so that it likely did the same when compiling the executing program. But that seems like a lot of work for nothing of much value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C (as in, defined by the language standard), no, there is no way.

There are however compiler-specific ways using which you can get really close to achieving what you want. The most famous, [as @Nate Eldredge notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454631/programmatically-determine-that-variables-value-was-computed-at-compile-time-or/64455059#comment113972142_64454631) in the comments, is the builtin function `__builtin_constant_p()` available in GCC and Clang.

Here's the relevant excerpt [from the GCC doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_constant_p (exp)`
>
> You can use the built-in function `__builtin_constant_p` to determine if a value is known to be constant at compile time and hence that GCC can perform constant-folding on expressions involving that value. The argument of the function is the value to test. The function returns the integer 1 if the argument is known to be a compile-time constant and 0 if it is not known to be a compile-time constant. A return of 0 does not indicate that the value is not a constant, but merely that GCC cannot prove it is a constant with the specified value of the `-O` option.

**Note that** this function does not guarantee to detect *all* compile-time constants, but only the ones that GCC is able to prove as such. Different optimization levels might change the result returned by this function.

This built-in function is widely used in glibc for optimization purposes ([example](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/wcsmbs/bits/wchar2.h.html#44)), and usually the result is only trusted when it's 1, assuming a non-constant otherwise:

```c
void somefunc(int x) {
    if (__builtin_constant_p(x)) {
        // Perform optimized operation knowing x is a compile-time constant.
    } else {
        // Assume x is not a compile-time constant.
    }
}
```

Using your own example:

```c
const double a = 2.0;
const double b = 3.0;
double c1 = a / b; // done at compile time (constant folding / propagation)
double c2 = *(volatile double*)&a / *(volatile double*)&b; // done at run time

assert(__builtin_constant_p(c1));
assert(!__builtin_constant_p(c2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask,

> Is there a way in C to programmatically determine that variable's
> value was computed at compile time or at run time?

No, there is no way to encode such a determination into the source of a strictly conforming C program.

Certainly C does not require values to be tagged systematically in a way that distinguishes among them based on when they were computed, and no C implementation I have ever heard of or imagined does that, so such a determination cannot be based on the values of the expressions of interest.  Furthermore, all C function arguments are passed by value, so the hypothetical `compute_time()` cannot be implemented as a function because values are all it would have to work with.

`compute_time()` also cannot be a macro, because macros can work only with (preprocessing) *tokens*, for example the identifiers `c1` and `c2` in your example code.  Those are opaque to the preprocessor; it knows nothing about values attributed to them when they are evaluated as expressions according to C semantics.

And there is no operator that serves the purpose.

Standard C provides no other alternatives, so if the question is about the C language and not any particular implementation of it then that's the end of the story.  Moreover, although it is conceivable that a given C implementation would provide your `compute_time()` or a functional equivalent as an extension, I am unaware of any that do. (However, see [@MarcoBonelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64455059/2402272), for an example of a similar, but not identical, extension.)